# Why does Android not detect any press of physical buttons on mobile phone devices?

Tags: android, android-button, logcat

I am using Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 2 and when I press for instance the power or volume physical button on my physical mobile phone the log is empty. I use two different devices one with Android 12 (Samsung A10 ) and the second with Android 8.

**My goal** here is to detect the press of the power button so I can save some logs to DB before the power command is executed.

This is the code that I use to detect any press of physical buttons:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        int keyPressed = event.getKeyCode();

        Log.d("MainActivity","\nonKeyDown" +
                "\nkey code: " + keyCode + "" +
                "\nevent key pressed: " + keyPressed );

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }





   @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        int keyPressed = event.getKeyCode();
        Log.d("MainActivity","\ndispatchKeyEvent" +
                "\nevent key pressed: " + keyPressed );
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> My goal here is to detect the press of the power button

AFAIK, that button press is not sent to apps, but instead is purely handled by the system. The HOME button works similarly.

You are welcome to try to listen to `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` broadcasts, if you'd like. However...

> so I can save some logs to DB before the power command is executed.

That is not really going to work, in terms of the "before the power command is executed" part. The OS is not going to wait around for a bunch of apps to do arbitrary things before processing that button press.

Also, please bear in mind that prior to Android 14, your process is likely to be terminated just by being in the background. Saving logs until a power button press means that you are going to lose those logs. Instead, save them immediately or perhaps periodically.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *"The HOME button works similarly."* 

I am detecting the press of the home button without any issues and using View Model I am saving some data to DB. 

Then in Activity using observer, I am executing what the home button should do.

Comment: @DevPeter: That never used to work. It's also not particularly useful. There are many other ways that your app can be moved to the background that do not involve a HOME button press (or the equivalent gesture). Focusing your attention on a couple of buttons runs the risk of either ignoring all those other possibilities or duplicating your work.

Comment: [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) In this specific case, my focus is on "Human error". 

While someone downloads important information you do not want the user to press the Back or Home button(or you can react). 

When the user presses the Power button then you want to know about it for future investigation.

 In terms of saving some data (String log), I can use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState, however, if I do not know what causing it (power button) then what is the point?